# Price calculator displaying result via html input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having some trouble with a pricing calculator, more specifically trying to display the result to the user in a html input field. Code Below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var quantity,result;
    function setValues()
    {
        quantity = Number(document.getElementById("quantity").value);
    }

    function sum()
    {
        setValues();
        result = ((quantity-25)*25)+3000;
        if (result<3000) 
        {
            result=3000;
        }
        document.getElementById("price").value = result;
    }
</script>

<form class="pricing-form" action="pricing-mailer.php" method="post" name="pricing_quote" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <ul>
        <li id="calculate">
            <input type="button" onclick="sum()" value="sum" class="calculate">Calculate</button>
        </li>
        <li id="properties">
            <label for="quantity" id="for_label"><strong>How many properties do you manage?</strong></label><br />
            <input id="quantity" type="text"/>
        </li>

        <li id="price">
            <label for="price" id="total_label"><strong>Your client accounting would cost just</strong></label><br />
            <input id="price" type="text" value=""/>
         </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: What trouble?..Please explain your problem..

Comment: `id='price'` is been used twice

Answer (score 0):

Having two IDs of the same value is invalid HTML. However, if it does happen, getElementById() will return the first instance of that ID it finds.

There are two elements with an ID of `price`. Since the li is the first instance of the ID, it's trying to update the `value` property of the li element. Change the li element's ID to something else so they don't conflict.

Comment: It answers the question, no?

Comment: I am not disagree that It answers this question, but the comment is enough for these small bugs and we should not encourage these questions without proper explanation..Don't take it personally..

Comment: I'm not taking anything personally, I'm just unclear what criteria to use to determine a comment answer vs. proper answer. The question could use some editing, but I'm not sure it's without hope.